# add to bit after some hex value

Tags: c

hello all I am working on not project where I have to add 2 bit message id on my hex data string and I have no idea how to do that your help will be appreciated

```
char *fn = "\x60\x45\xd3\x94\x48\0x7c\0x19\xde\xea\x9a\x3e\x0e\xda\xc4\x9b\x81\x28\xb1\x0b\xff\</sensors>;ct=40;title=Sensor Index,</sensors/temp>;rt=temperature-c;if=sensor,</sensors/light>;rt=light-lux;if=sensor";
```

I need to add 2 bit message id after

Comment: C, C#, and most other languages cannot store and retrieve variables at less-than-byte precision (with the exception of small bitfields in a structure). So, adding "2 bits" to a variable is meaningless. You could add a byte that contains those 2 bits perhaps.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker You're right, however, it is not a limitation of the language, but a limitation of the underlying architecture.

Comment: I could create a programming language that allowed variables of any bit-length, that stored, retrieved, and printed them consistently, regardless of architecture. Of course, the architecture would determine *how* they were stored (just like it determines how things like floats are stored).

Answer (score 0):

Between two custom chips, you might be able to send 2 bits of data, but on modern computers, it must be aligned on 8 bits. Therefore, even tough you need to send 2 bits, you'll need to pad it with 6 bits to send a whole byte. This translates to adding a char to your fn string.

```
char *fn = "\x60\x45\xd3\x94\x48\0x7c\0x19\xde\xea\x9a\x3e\x0e\xda\xc4\x9b\x81\x28\xb1\x0b\xff\</sensors>;ct=40;title=Sensor Index,</sensors/temp>;rt=temperature-c;if=sensor,</sensors/light>;rt=light-lux;if=sensor";

int msgid = 0b11;
int fnlen = strlen(fn);
char fn2[fnlen + 2];

strcat(fn2, fn);
fn2[fnlen] = (char) msgid;
fn2[fnlen + 1] = '\0';
```